# How use object in image tag src

Tags: html, vue.js

How can I use object in img src?

```
// html
<img src= "item.img"
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a way to pass the url

```
<img :src="item.img"
```

if the above doesn't work then try the same using `require` just as below

```
<img :src="require(item.img)"
```

Assuming that `item` is an object with `img` property present in it

Comment: Cool, the above answer worked well. I didn't know the answer is adding the colon, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes that way how you send dynamic values

Comment: @Inforage Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer